# Compiler respond differently when assigning int.MaxValue to variable

Tags: c#

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) `int.MaxValue` is an int field. When I do

```
int a = int.MaxValue;
int b = a + 1;
```

`b` has the value of `int.MinValue` as expected. But when I do

```
int a = int.MaxValue + 1;
```

I get compilation error

> The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode

Why is the there a difference?

Comment: Don't know why this happens, just want to mention that this is expected behaviour when executing in a [`checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) block

Comment: `int a = unchecked(int.MaxValue + 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691319(v=vs.71).aspx:

> A constant-expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile-time.

and

> Whenever an expression is of one of the types listed above and contains only the constructs listed above, the expression is evaluated at compile-time.

and

> Unless a constant expression is explicitly placed in an unchecked context, overflows that occur in integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions during the compile-time evaluation of the expression always cause compile-time errors

So this explains why `int a = int.MaxValue + 1;` gives a compilation error (`int.MaxValue` is a `const int`).

The

```
int a = int.MaxValue;
int b = a + 1;
```

is different, because it isn't a constant-expression. They are two non-const variables (see the *and contains only the constructs listed above*? Clearly declaring an intermediate variable isn't one of the acceptable constructs :-) )

Comment: This seems to be the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the first line, you add two constants. `int.MaxValue` is a constant and 1 is, too. So the compiler does the calculation *at compile time* and fails with this warning.

The second line will produce the same behavior, but *at runtime*, because you have introduced a *variable* and your compiler does not optimize it enough to do the calculation at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler probably use [`checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) option (which is a default option) and it says;

> By default, an expression that contains **only constant values** causes a
>   compiler error if the expression produces a value that is outside the
>   range of the destination type. **If the expression contains one or more
>   non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow**.

Since both `int.MaxValue` and `1` is constant, you get the error.

If you use [`unchecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) option, you will see the same result

```
unchecked
{
    int a = int.MaxValue + 1; // a is int.MinValue
}
```